# Access Vuex Store in Blade file | Laravel - Vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuex, store

How can I access a method or variable defined in the Vuex 4 store in my Blade file?
I am using a compiled app.js from vite. Obviously in the components of Vue js I can access the store, I wonder if it is also possible to do it in a blade file.
Vue js #app instance must be one of course.
If at the end of my blade file I write this

```
 <script>
    import {useStore} from "vuex";
    import {onMounted, watch, ref, defineComponent} from 'vue'

    export default {
        setup() {
            const click = () => {
                store.commit('mutazione');
            };
            onMounted(() => {
                alert('test');
            })

            const store = useStore();
            return {

                store,
                click
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

the console gives me this type of error

```
 Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

Comment: nope, you can't. and you should not. this should be part of the vue app.

Answer (score -1):

First Leave laravel out of it. You cant anything with blade for that.

Blade is backend for render in php.

And Vue is usually spa thing.

It is purely vuex5.0 / Pinia https://pinia.vuejs.org job to do.

Best practice is Create the store of every type of data you need like
https://github.com/puneetxp/the check test directly in it totally in JavaScript you can see like create Store assume it is for Product data.

```
import { defineStore, acceptHMRUpdate } from "/js/vue/pinia.js";
export const useProductStore = defineStore({
    id: "Product",
    state: () => ({
        rawItems: [],
    }),
    getters: {
        items: (state) => state.rawItems
    },
    actions: {
        addItem(product) {
            this.rawItems.push(product)
        },
        removeItem(id) {
            this.rawItems = this.rawItems.filter(i => i.id != id);
        },
        editItem(product) {
            this.rawItems = this.rawItems.filter(i => i.id != product.id);
            this.rawItems.push(product);
        },
        upsertItem(products) {
            products.forEach(product => {
                this.rawItems = this.rawItems.filter(i => i.id != product.id);
                this.rawItems.push(product);
            });
        }
    },
})

if (import.meta.hot) {
    import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(useActive_roleStore, import.meta.hot))
}
```

then we can use in your component

```
import { useProductStore } from "/js/vue/Store/Model/Product.js";
export default {
    template: ``,
    data() {
        return {
            useProductStore,
        }
    }
}
```

for use use it on useProductStore().items as my design you can make your own if you want.

Comment: You didn't answer the question itself